# Why aren't modules path being resolved properly after transpiling using tsc

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

So, I started using ts for the backend and used this as my tsconfig.json.

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {

   "target": "es2016",                                   

   /* Modules */
"module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
"moduleResolution": "Node10",                     /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
"baseUrl": "./src",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
"paths": {
"@/*" : ["*"]
},  
"esModuleInterop": true,                                      
"skipLibCheck": true,
"outDir": "./dist"

 }
}
```

And after doing npx tsc (npm run build), I get the ./dist created but when I run ./dist/index.js, I get the following errors ->

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1152
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module '@/routes'
```